# How to access Local<String> in a node.js AddOn

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I've written an Addon for node.js in which I want to use the arguments passed to my c++ code.

```
void tdlNodeAddOnClass::my_func( const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

  if ( args[0]->IsString() )
  {
    Local<String> Value = args[0]->ToString();
  }
}
```

How can I access the actual c-style buffer ?
Is there any better documentation or tutorial than the v5.6.0 Documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
if (args[0]->IsString()) {
  Local<String> val = args[0]->ToString();
  Utf8Value str(isolate, val);
}
```

You could then access the underlying `char *` by doing `*str`

Comment: Is there any documentation for helper-classes such as Utf8Value anywhere ?

Comment: I don't believe so. I would definitely recommend using nan though to make supporting multiple versions of node easier. There is also a Nan::Utf8String. Documentation for that can be found at https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/v8_misc.md#nanutf8string. The actual code for node::Utf8Value can be found at https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/util.h#L181-L206. A PR with documentation on that would be welcome at https://github.com/nodejs/node though.